# Java library for NodeRelation Graph (NRG)

Tags: java, graph

I want to write a program that creates a NRG from a map structure.
This graph should keep the topology relation of the map structure.
Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: you want an api to make graph if i understand ?

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for an APi for graph :

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) sounds like what you're after.

JGraphT is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms. JGraphT supports various types of graphs.

Their API can create graphs from various input and also supports creating graphs using addVertex, addEdge. They support finding shortest paths using various well know algorithms such as Bellman-Ford and Dijkstra They also have a complete [javadoc available online](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/).